# limit attachment on qmail

Tags: attachment, qmail

Is it possible to limit the size of attachment that can be send or received in qmail. Its to stop mail forwardings with large sizes amoung employees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum message size for emails in a qmail-installation is normally defined by the following file:

```
./qmail/control/databytes
```

The size is defined in bytes. Example:

```
50000000
```

Limit would be: 50000000Bytes = 48,828Kb = 47,68MB